# libc and undefined symbol: stime

Tags: glibc, libc

I have an python application that uses the FTDI driver library named:

```
/usr/local/lib64/libftd2xx.so.1.4.22
```

When I run the application using libc 2.27, it works fine.

When running it against libc 2.32 it fails with the following:

```
/usr/local/lib64/libftd2xx.so: undefined symbol: stime
```

While looking at the libc release, indeed there is something related to stime from libc 2.31 as described at: https://lwn.net/Articles/811315/

It says:

> "The obsolete function stime is no longer available to newly linked
> binaries, and its declaration has been removed from <time.h>."

My understanding from this is that only "new code" cannot compile/link with this function but an existing library that were using this function should still work.

In fact if I look for the stime symbol the rough the below command in both 2.27 and the 2.32 I find that stime is there:

2.27

```
root@PPL23:~# nm --demangle --dynamic --defined-only --extern-only /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so* | grep stime
00000000000d5ee0 T stime
```

2.32

```
localhost /tmp #  nm --demangle --dynamic --defined-only --extern-only /lib64/libc-2.32.so | grep stime
000000000012e490 T stime@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Why is libc 2.32 not backward compatible with the existing FTDI driver? Shouldn't that work even with 2.32 version since the symbol seems to be there?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is why libc does not achieve the backwards compatibility

Answer (score 6):

According to the man page [stime(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stime.2.html) is deprecated.

> NOTE: This function is deprecated; use clock_settime(2) instead.

Instead of:

```c
stime(100)
```

following code can be used:

```c
clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, (struct timespec*){100,0})
```

If for some reason you want to go with `stime` anyway, you may use the assembly trick proposed in the [SymbolVersioning](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SymbolVersioning)

```c
__asm__(".symver stime,stime@GLIBC_2.2.5");
```